# packaging and deploying a java application with java DB in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have developed a java application not a java desktop application with a java DB to interact with it,  all in netbeans. Now i want to package it and deploy it for distribution. So i guess the java DB must be in an embedded mode in order to communicate very well with the application. So how do i do this?

Comment: Please someone should help me answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/399770/packaging-and-deploying-java-with-database-using-netbeans-6.8) article can help you. Check if you are using the latest version of the sql connector, [Connector/J 5.1.25](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) is the latest.